# How to check character repetition in string?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

Hi guy's I am new to the regex and i am trying the create the expression for the pattern of the string value the rules are as below

```
1) String must start with the 'O' or 'T'
2) After that there must be 9 digits 
3) After that there must be 'T'
4) After that alphanumeric string with specs and numbers and character'D' these can repeat any number of time in string of length 25 
5) Then character 'O'
6) Then string with numbers and spaces of length 5
```

However i am done with the all the conditions but for the condition **4** i am not sure how to do it because it can repeat 'D' any number of times in given string with length 25. Write now i have adjusted the optional 'D' at every place where it present in the string that is kind of very lengthy regex so I was hoping some one would help me with condition **4** .Any help would be great.

The string to match -->

```
T011600062TO51D45D0399D0O 1807
```

The latest regex -->

```
(?x)((?:[OT]\d{9})(?:T\s*\d*\s*[0-9DO ]\d*\s*[OD0-9 ]\s*\d*[D0-9]\s*\d*[0-9OD ]\d*)(?:[O]\s*\d*)\b)
```

I am confused about this part of regex

```
(?:T\s*\d*\s*[0-9DO ]\d*\s*[OD0-9 ]\s*\d*[D0-9]\s*\d*[0-9OD ]\d*)
```

is this the correct way ?

Comment: Could you post your latest regex?

Comment: @Jerry - I have added the latest regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this for the all your matching pattern ,

```
(O|T)\d{9}T[DO \d]{0,25}O[\d ]{5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Condition 4 is not clear.

`(O|T)\d{9}T[D\d]{25}O[\d ]{5}`

Comment: @Kriomant- 4th condition -- The string with length of 25 or less characters between 'T' and 'O' that 25 or less characters can contain   only numbers,white spaces and the character 'D' any number of times and character 'O' for one time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is D{0,25}. it means D repeated 0~25 times.